# OS X: How does drag source know in what application the drop occurred?

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

If I drag an item from my apps view and drag
 it successfully, if it was dropped in the same document, I know from the drag destination methods. If it was dropped in another document window of the same app, I need to notify the source document somehow. I can probably figure out a way to do that, but it seems like an unnecessary hack.

On the other hand, if it was dropped successively on another app, there seems to be no way to know what app it was dropped on. Presumably, one can use 
- draggingSession:endedAtPoint:operation:

but there might be any number of apps over that screen point.

If dropped on the source document, the item should just move. If dropped on another document of the same app, it should move from one document to the other. If dropped on a different app, it should just be copied there, not moved, so it is important to know where it has gone.

I've looked for examples or other documentation for some hours without any joy. There should be a simple way of doing this, but I've missed it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you implement `- (NSDragOperation)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session
sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext:(NSDraggingContext)context`?

Comment: Yes.  It is implemented. I just checked.

Comment: Which `NSDragOperation` do you return?

Comment: NSDragOperationCopy.

Comment: Return NSDragOperationCopy for outside application and NSDragOperationMove for within application. Or put several (promised) types on the pasteboard and let the destination deside what to do.

Comment: Or implement a separate message back method, always do a copy and then in your app implement a notification that the receiver sends - basically "Got your data ok" and have the source listen for that and delete the source if received. That way you can guard against data loss if something goes wrong in the receiving end.